# Determine whether two single-linked lists are identical or not?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, match

I want to determine whether two single-linked lists are identical or not. 
If they are identical, the program should print matched letters.

Examples: 
murmur   and  tartar   are identical, because they both have the same pattern  "abcabc".

AAABBCbbaaa    and   11122322111     are identical

Matched letters: 
A ↔ 1 
B ↔ 2 
C ↔ 3

I must use ONLY single linked list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a string:");
    String linked1=scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter another string:");
    String linked2=scanner.nextLine();

    SingleLinkedList SLL1 = new SingleLinkedList();
    SingleLinkedList SLL2 = new SingleLinkedList();


    for (int i = 0; i < linked1.length(); i++) {
        char  a=linked1.charAt(i);
        a = Character.toLowerCase(a);
        SLL1.addToEnd(a);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < linked2.length(); i++) {
        char  a=linked2.charAt(i);
        a = Character.toLowerCase(a);
        SLL2.addToEnd(a);
    }


public class SingleLinkedList{

private Node head;

public SingleLinkedList()
{
    head = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return head == null;
}
public void addToEnd(Object dataToAdd)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(dataToAdd);

    if(head == null)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node temp = head;

        while(temp.getLink() != null)
        {
           temp = temp.getLink();
        }

        temp.setLink(newNode);
    }
}
public String display()
{
    String output = "";

    Node temp = head;

    while(temp != null)
    {
       output += temp.getData() + " ";
       temp = temp.getLink();
    }

    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried creating 2 temp single llinked ist then, i thought removing chars to this temps. but the order is important i cant make it correctly. Doest work well

Comment: What have you tried so far to compare the two lists for equality? We can help you with problems you encounter, but first you have to try something. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: for example lets say that string is Jelly_Bean if i encrypt this string 1-2-3-3-4-5-6-2-7-8-9 like this, i can equal two string. but i couldnt make this encryption

Comment: How are you 'encrypting'? What about murmur and tartar. You say they are the same. How would you compare those two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it's a tedious work and I haven't got the strength to write the actual code.

You should *encode* (not *encrypt*) your sequences.

A trivial way of encoding your list is to iterate it's values, each value you pick must be checked against a seq of already encountered values.

If the value is not present on the check seq, you add it and go on.

At the end of this you will have a seq of unique values ordered as you found them.

Then, for each element of your seq you find which is the position in your check set, and build a new seq of those positions.

You repeat it for both your sequences, and then you can match your encoded sequences.

You should create an indexOf method for your seq to simplify your program.

Comment: thanks for your answering. i am gonna try with your directions.